# Why are move contructors implicitly deleted for my class?

Tags: c++, c++11, grpc, copy-constructor, move-constructor

The following code...

```
// main.cpp
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>

class ClientContextContainer {
public:
  ClientContextContainer( int i ) : i_(i) {}

private:
  grpc::ClientContext client_context_;
  int i_;
};

class ArrayContainer {
public:
  ArrayContainer() : ccc_{ {42}, {1138} } {}

private:
  ClientContextContainer ccc_[2];
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  ArrayContainer ac;

 return 0;
}
```

...generates this error:

```
root@178258c7c52d:/tmp# /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ --version && /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -c ./main.cpp
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

./main.cpp: In constructor 'ArrayContainer::ArrayContainer()':
./main.cpp:15:41: error: use of deleted function 'ClientContextContainer::ClientContextContainer(ClientContextContainer&&)'
   ArrayContainer() : ccc_{ {42}, {1138} } {}
                                         ^
./main.cpp:4:7: note: 'ClientContextContainer::ClientContextContainer(ClientContextContainer&&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class ClientContextContainer {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./main.cpp:4:7: error: 'grpc::ClientContext::ClientContext(const grpc::ClientContext&)' is private within this context
In file included from /usr/local/include/grpcpp/client_context.h:37,
                 from /usr/local/include/grpcpp/grpcpp.h:53,
                 from ./main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/client_context.h:388:3: note: declared private here
   ClientContext(const ClientContext&);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I do not fully understand the compiler error, but by my reading, it implies that the problem is that `class ClientContextContainer`'s move constructor is implicitly deleted because the class' member `grpc::ClientContext` object has a private copy constructor. (Inspection of `client_context.h` shows that its assignment operator is also private).

Fine. But if that's the case, **why can't I reproduce the compile error if I replace the `grpc::ClientContext` member object with my own object that also has a private copy constructor (and assignment operator)?**

```
// main.cpp
//#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>

class FauxClientContext {
public:
  FauxClientContext() {}

private:
  FauxClientContext( const FauxClientContext& );
  FauxClientContext& operator=( const FauxClientContext& );
};

class ClientContextContainer {
public:
  ClientContextContainer( int i ) : i_(i) {}

private:
  FauxClientContext client_context_;
  //grpc::ClientContext client_context_;
  int i_;
};

class ArrayContainer {
public:
  ArrayContainer() : ccc_{ {42}, {1138} } {}

private:
  ClientContextContainer ccc_[2];
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  ArrayContainer ac;

 return 0;
}
```

```
root@178258c7c52d:/tmp# /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ --version && /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -c ./main.cpp
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

root@178258c7c52d:/tmp#
```

**What's the true nature of the error compiling the first version of `main.cpp`?** That I could successfully compile the second version of `main.cpp` implies that it's not what I interpreted the compiler error message to mean.

---

To those familiar with `grpc`, the root of this line of inquiry is: **is it possible to construct an array of objects, in an initializer-list, if the objects have a member `grpc::ClientContext` object?**

Comment: In the old days, pre C++11, one of the better ways way to block copy construction was to make the copy constructor `private` and not implement it. It looks like `grpc::ClientContext` is designed to not be copy-able.

Comment: Now I guess the question is "Why does one trigger the copy constructor and the other not?" Dunno. If I did, I'd answer.

Comment: You might find it illuminating and/or mystifying to add the line `ClientContextContainer(ClientContextContainer&&) = delete;` to your definition of `ClientContextContainer`. That is, instead of trying to make the move constructor *implicitly* deleted, make it *explicitly* deleted. ***Spoiler:*** it still compiles.

Comment: @JaMit For g++ (with -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedanti) it won't compile as soon as you introduce a non trivial member to FauxClientContext (as did the clientContext class of grpc) but it will with MSBuild C++17 nonconformance at least.

Comment: Is this a question about grpc or about move constructors in general?

Comment: It's a compiler bug. I modified my answer and things should now be clear here.

Answer (score 3):

My original post contained too much speculation and further analysis of your issue, the first update of my answer contained a misassumption about the actual underlying issues here further on unfortunately. So this answer should be the final version and addresses all relevant issues here hopefully.

**When are move constructors implicitly deleted:**

Excerpt from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted move constructor for class T is
> defined as deleted if any of the following is true:
>
> - T has non-static data members that cannot be moved (have deleted,    inaccessible, or ambiguous move constructors);
> - T has direct or virtual base class that cannot be moved (has deleted,    inaccessible, or ambiguous move constructors);
> - T has direct or virtual base class with a deleted or inaccessible    destructor;
> - T is a union-like class and has a variant member with non-trivial    move constructor.
>
> A defaulted move constructor that is deleted is ignored by overload
> resolution (otherwise it would prevent copy-initialization from
> rvalue).

**Why you get a compile error:**

According to the standard at least already since C++11, you shouldn't actually since you use the C++11 direct list initialization syntax (see your array) with a well defined constructor for your case correctly. Copy and move constructors are not required here for your case at least. g++ has a still not fixed bug (almost historical now) that causes your problems here, see

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63707

Your compiler works standard conformably (as far as I was able to test it) at least as long as your class ClientContextContainer doesn't hold a member whose according class destructor isn't implicitly (default) defined. That's not the case for grpc::ClientContext since it has several members (shared pointers) with non-default destructors. That's why, your modified code snippet with this simple class works well even for the case where all copy/move constructors are private/deleted. Try to introduce a critical member here in terms of the destructor and you'll be able to reproduce the compile error quickly.

Side note:

Your actual issue here has nothing to do with guaranteed copy elision - introduced in C++17 (that was my misassumption here actually). Maybe it has an indirect relevance here with focus on this g++ bug since if the bug is a missing direct initialization but an illegal underlying usage of copy-initialization, g++ also would violate the guaranteed copy elision requirement of the standard since C++17 here for your case I think.

For further information, see

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr: It's a compiler bug.

This is a bug in the GCC compiler:

[Brace initialization of array sometimes fails if no copy constructor](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63707) (gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla)

It has been fixed, as of the time of writing, for GCC 11.0, 10.3 and 9.4, but manifests in currently released versions upto and including 10.2.

A reduced testcase due to Jonathan Wakeley:

```
struct NonCopyable {
  NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
  NonCopyable(NonCopyable&&) = delete;
  NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
  NonCopyable& operator=(NonCopyable&&) = delete;

  NonCopyable() {}

  ~NonCopyable() {} // makes the destructor non-trivial
};

struct A {
  A(): _a{} {}
  ~A() {}

  NonCopyable _a[5];
} a;
```

This works with clang, fails with GCC (see it on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/6E847Y)).

Comment: Thanks for the update! Only a theory: They hurried up to fix this one since Peter Dimov from Boost mentioned his encounter with this one there too... :)

Comment: @Secundi: Whaaat? I thought it was all on my account :-P